# File upload with html and phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have some trouble with sending e-mails including files from my html form with the phpmailer script. I am able to sent images and files that already are on the server. I do this by adding

```
  $mail->AddAttachment('404.jpg');
```

to the phpmailer script. But when I want the user to add a file he want to send from his computer with the other information (name, e-mail, address etc.) from the html form, phpmailer does send a e-mail without the file.

Here is my code for the html form without files:

```
<form id="form_907007" class="appnitro" method="post" action="Server/phpmailer.php">
```

and with files:

```
<form id="form_907007" class="appnitro" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Server/phpmailer.php">
<p>Choose data (txt, html etc.)<br>
<input name="file" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000">
</p>
</form>
```

I guess the phpmailer does not really get the file. I edit my code like this to handle the file from the form:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
$_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['file']['name']);}
```

without success, can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: What happened with the form id? I mean at the form with files.

Comment: copy and paste ;) it is still there

Comment: I don't see any error in your code.

Comment: You need to treat this as two problems: file upload and email an attachment. Solve the upload first, then the attachment. You should use `move_uploaded_file` before passing the file to PHPMailer.